# Passing Jupyter Widget Dropdown list to second dropdown

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've got an issue that pertains to how to use jupyter widgets, dropdowns namely, to produce a workflow. Currently my intentions aren't working, and I am aiming to do the following:

1. Run a function that produces a list
2. This list is fed into a dropdown, from which I select one (x)
3. x refers to another function, that has a dictionary, it picks up all values associated with this key, and produces another list
4. The list is fed into another dropdown, from where I'd pick one value for processing.

Issue that I am coming up with, is that I can get the first list produced and fed into a dropdown. However the subsequent list is not captured, and rather the function is, which of course fails down the road. Let me illustrate with some code:

This bit of code simply goes through a list of dictionaries, and places all the unique league instances into a list:

```
def league_names():
    league_list = []
    data_filenames = [data_file for data_file in os.listdir() 
              if data_file.endswith('.json')]
    with open(data_filenames[0]) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
    for x in data:
        if x['Competition'] is not None and x['Competition'] not in league_list:
            league_list.append(x['Competition'])
    return league_list[1:]
```

What the following will then do, is take that list, and search the same set of dictionaries, search for all the teams that are a part of that league, and add them to a list.

```
def team_names(league_select):
    team_list = []
    data_filenames = [data_file for data_file in os.listdir() 
              if data_file.endswith('.json')]
    with open(data_filenames[0]) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
    for x in data:
        if x['Competition'] == league_select and x['Team'] not in team_list:
            team_list.append(x['Team'])
    return team_list
```

How I want to interact with this, is that the first league list is passed to a dropdown, from which you pick a league. This passes the league to the second function, to pull all the teams. How this is done is with the following:

```
def league_interact():
    choice = interact(team_names, league_select=league_names())
    return type(choice)
league_interact()
```

Now this works, the list is successfully passed through, however what I simply cannot get to work, is for the interact from here to be transformed into a variable, that I can then pass to a subsequent function for further processing.

Below is an example of the json content:

```
[{"Team": "Yeovil Town FC", "Gender": "M", "Competition": "National League", "Earliest Season": "2003-2004", "Latest Season": "2020-2021", "Total Seasons": "18", "Championships": "1", "Other Names": "", "Code": "bd5179b9", "Prefix": "Yeovil-Town-Stats"}, 
{"Team": "Yeovil Town LFC", "Gender": "F", "Competition": "", "Earliest Season": "2017", "Latest Season": "2018-2019", "Total Seasons": "3", "Championships": "", "Other Names": "", "Code": "a506e4a2", "Prefix": "Yeovil-Town-Women-Stats"}, 
{"Team": "York City FC", "Gender": "M", "Competition": "", "Earliest Season": "2002-2003", "Latest Season": "2019-2020", "Total Seasons": "13", "Championships": "0", "Other Names": "", "Code": "e272e7a8", "Prefix": "York-City-Stats"}, 
{"Team": "Yorkshire Amateur AFC", "Gender": "M", "Competition": "", "Earliest Season": "2019-2020", "Latest Season": "2020-2021", "Total Seasons": "0", "Championships": "", "Other Names": "", "Code": "66379800", "Prefix": "Yorkshire-Amateur-AFC-Stats"}]
```

Question: How would I in the above case, use interact to produce the list created by the first choice, rather than a function? I have the type pulled here, where it is a 'function' rather than a list as expected. I tried using .value, and some derivatives, but none of them pushed out a value. Any idea how to approach this, so I can produce a secondary dropdown?

I've tried the following, but getting an error:

```
def league_interact():
    choice = interact(team_names, league_select=league_names())
    return choice
def team_interact():
    choice2 = interact(team_code, team_select=league_interact())
team_interact()
```

Error: ValueError: <function team_names at 0x0000021359D20B80> cannot be transformed to a widget

Thanks! I did trawl through the documentation, but how to approach this didn't quite click with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I actually managed to figure this out:

```
@interact(league = league_box)
def choose_both(league):
    team_box.options = team_names(league_box.value)
    return

@interact_manual(team = team_box, use_season = season_box)
def choose_team(team, use_season):
    return team_choice_cap(team_data(team),use_season)

def team_choice_cap(data_set, use_season):
    code = data_set['Code']
    prefix = data_set['Prefix']
    return parse_seasons(code,prefix,use_season)
```

The above interact and interact_manual can be used to feed the latter list, that then works to pull up with a manual call the rest of the details.